# How to present graphically the age groups of people that smoke?

Tags: r, bar-chart, grouping

I am working with "survey" data frame that contains data for university students. I have split the students into 3 age groups (0-20), (20 - 25), (25+).

And now I am trying to present graphically the age groups and their smoke habits.

I tried the following script

```
Age_Group <- cut(survey$Age, breaks=c(0, 20, 25, Inf), 
                 labels=c("0-20", "20-25", "25+"))
survey2 <- survey
survey2 <- cbind(survey2, Age_Group)

barplot(table(survey2$Age, survey2$Smoke, legend.text=TRUE, beside=TRUE))
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error in table(survey2$Age_Group, survey2$Smoke, legend.text = TRUE, beside = TRUE): 
  all arguments must have the same length
```

Comment: survey2$Age_Group   not survey2$Age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have a parenthesis in the wrong place.

```
barplot(table(survey2$Age, survey2$Smoke, legend.text=TRUE, beside=TRUE))
```

should be:

```
barplot(table(survey2$Age, survey2$Smoke), legend.text=TRUE, beside=TRUE)
```

It is reading table as having four columns, with the last two have only one element.
I think you want below.  I created a sample data set to test the code with.

```
survey <- data.frame(Age=(30*rnorm(1000) + 45), Smoke=as.numeric(runif(1000) < .2))
Age_Group <- cut(survey$Age, breaks=c(0, 20, 25, Inf), labels=c("0-20", "20-25", "25+"))
survey2 <- survey
survey2 <- cbind(survey2, Age_Group)
barplot(table(survey2$Smoke, survey2$Age_Group), legend.text=TRUE, beside=TRUE)
```

Comment: Your improvement of the code is exactly what I needed.
Thank you so much for jumping in
However, if you have the time, could you explain the process behind:

"survey=data.frame(Age= (30*rnorm(1000)+45),Smoke=as.numeric(runif(1000)<.2))"

Comment: I just created a sample data frame using random numbers to test the code. The age will be centered about 45 and have a standard deviation of 30.  About 20% of the sample will smoke.